# SAG Webmethods - Time line

Tags: webmethods

I'm using Software AG Designer and webMethods since few days and I would like to know if it's possible to add a time line for my process?

Let me explain more precisely: when I publish and run my process on SAG Designer I can see it on Webmethods by clicking on "Process Instance". Still in this part, is it possible to see the time line of the process ? To have a global view of it ?

I would like this kind of result :

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: The problem I see is, that there might be (and it is you case too) several paths to the end. Different paths may have different times needed for execution. I'm afraid this is not solveable in general, so it is also not supported out of the box in wM...

Comment: Maybe several "timelines" in this case ? I'm almost sure I heard that it was possible

Comment: Or maybe just by adding some "flags". For example if we are running this activity, we will put the progression bar at this point. In fact, define the milestones by ourself.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want to see?

[image: Process execution steps]

To be able to see this, you have to set logging level to 5:

[image: Process settings]

Screenshots are from 9.8 version.

As I asked in comment, please specify, what you meant by "time line".

Comment: Thank you for answering. In fact it's not exactly what I want but I'am aware that I was not clear.

Comment: So please rephrase your question (not a new one is needed) to make it more clear and maybe we will find a solution ;-)

Comment: I would like to have graph to follow the progression of the process.This graph will be able to know how many activities are finished and evaluate the evolution of the process and the time staying to go to the end. (Btw, I added a new picture inside my first post)